# Comment dit-on « movie director » en français?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, cinéma, théatre

Est-ce vrai, qu'en français on dit :

> Réalisateur

pour le directeur d'un film et :

> Metteur en scène

pour le directeur d'une pièce de théâtre ?

J'ai trouvé ces mots en Babbel, mais je ne suis pas sûr notamment pour « réalisateur », qui semble un peu dépassé...

Comment: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9alisateur  confirme vos propositions et défini les métiers du cinéma en France et au États-Unis. Réalisateur est toujours en usage pour le cinéma.

Comment: En revanche, directeur d'un film et directeur d'une pièce de théâtre sont des anglicismes. Les directeurs que l'on peut rencontrer dans les métiers du cinéma sont ceux de la photo, du casting et de la production. Il y a aussi bien sûr les directeurs de théâtres.

Comment: Here's the [website](http://frenchfilmfestival.us/2014-film-festival-schedule) for this year's (the 23rd annual) (March 26-29) VCU/Univ. of Richmond French Film Festival that we're lucky enough to have here in central Virginia. If you download the program (under the "Program 2015" rubric on the banner), you'll see "Réalisateur" used for "Director" when they describe in French interviews with and comments by directors (see page 13 for one example). On page 11, you'll see the use of "DIRECTEUR de la photographie (for cinematographer)," as mentioned by @jlliagre. Definitely worth the trip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une note sur l'étymologie et l'histoire pour appuyer l'usage de *réalisateur*. À l'origine, le verbe réaliser vient du domaine du droit et de la finance. A. Rey note dans le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*(ed. Le Robert) « dans son sens courant de « rendre réel, effectif » (1611), réaliser est un verbe didactique en philosophie et s'oppose à idéaliser. »; il indique aussi que « faire (un film) » c'est 1908. La [*réalisation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9alisation) constitue l'ensemble des opérations requises à cette fin. La définition de [*réalisateur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9alisateur) rend bien le tout en effet, et la remarque est fort intéressante:

> Personne qui a la responsabilité de la fabrication d'un film ou d'une
>   émission de télévision, qui assure notamment la direction des acteurs,
>   des prises de vues et de son, du montage et de la sonorisation. Synon.
>   vieilli metteur* en scène.
>   [...]
>
> **Rem.** En 1936, René Clair note que *metteur en scène* reste le terme usuel: Le réalisateur (*rappelons qu'en France le terme le plus souvent
>   employé au sujet de cet emploi est « metteur en scène », appellation
>   moins significative que le mot allemand « régisseur » ou le mot
>   anglais « director »*) dirige en principe l'ensemble de la réalisation
>   (Arts et litt., loc. cit.). Jean Vilar aurait souhaité que *réalisateur*
>   soit substitué à *metteur en scène* aussi dans la langue du théâtre:
>   *Jean Vilar, avec sa méfiance habituelle des mots, n'aime pas le titre
>   de metteur en scène, ni celui d'animateur. Il leur préfère,
>   semble-t-il, le terme de « réalisateur », et, assurément, celui de «
>   régisseur », l'un et l'autre étant d'une acception plus artisanale*
>   (Serrière, T.N.P., 1959, p. 168).
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé - TLFi ]

Essentiellement identique en [contexte](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8401777) nord-américain en ce qui a trait à la terminologie. Le [cinéma](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cin%C3%A9ma) est un *art du spectacle*, couramment désigné en français comme le « septième art ». L'[artisan](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/artisan) qu'est le *réalisateur* est responsable de réaliser l’œuvre en film. L'accent est davantage le métier que la régie, d'une certaine manière, même si le terme englobe le contrôle et la responsabilité de toutes les étapes.

Comment: There's that word "métier" again! Nice discussion of "régisseur" and the difference between 'le métier' & 'la régie.'

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks! I didn't know any of this; I really like that réalisation has this concrete aspect grounded in the craft. Note the [_régisseur_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358442) exists in the non-German sense in French... seems ironically that's the _assistant director in English!

Answer (score 6):

Effectivement, « [réalisateur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9alisateur) » est utilisé au cinéma et « [metteur en scène](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/metteur) » est utilisé au théâtre pour dire *director*.

La différence vient probablement du fait qu’au cinéma, le réalisateur crée (*réalise*) une nouvelle œuvre alors qu’au théâtre, le metteur en scène supervise la production d’une œuvre généralement créée par quelqu’un d’autre.

Answer (score 2):

Oui, tout le monde utilise *réalisateur* pour *director*.

À ne pas confondre avec *producteur* (en: *producer*), qui finance le film.

Vous pouvez vérifier les métiers du cinéma sur l'équivalent Français de IMDB, [AlloCiné](http://www.allocine.fr/).